# Cannot capture exception details in @Override in JUnit4

Tags: java, junit

```
@Rule
public MethodRule watchman = new TestWatchman() {
    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable e, FrameworkMethod method) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Exception =" + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertTrue(false);
    }
};
```

The code that causes the failure is :

```
assertTrue("Missing first picture",selenium.isElementPresent("//div/a/img[2]"));
```

My question is how do I pass the error message "Missing first picture" to the `@Override` so that it prints out that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to why your MethodRule.failed method contains the statement `assertTrue(false)`.  For the sake of this discussion I will assume that you added that statement for testing and then did not remove it for this post.

The Assert.assertTrue method, when fails, causes a `java.lang.AssertionError` to be thrown with it's message value being set to the text you supplied as the first parameter to the `assertTrue` method.  In order to retrieve that value you simply invoke the following: `e.getMessage()`.

Here is an example of a Method rule that prints out the success and failure results of the tests being monitored to System.err (used as example only):

```
@Rule
public MethodRule watchman = new TestWatchman() {
    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable e, FrameworkMethod method) {
        System.err.println(method.getName() + "() failed with error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void succeeded(FrameworkMethod method) {
        System.err.println(method.getName() + "() succeeded");
    }
};
```

If you use this example with the following tests:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    assertTrue("will not happen", true);
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    assertTrue("My error message", false);
}
```

You will see the following:

```
test1() succeeded
test2() failed with error: My error message
```

Comment: Hi Kris, your code works, thanks. My error is actually triggered in another class that I call from my JUnit test.         @Test  
 public void test5OrderPage() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
  OrderPageCheck affOrderPageCheck = new OrderPageCheck(selenium);   
  affOrderPageCheck.check(); 
 }                                                               It is the check() method that has the assertTrue statement. But the code above does not capture the error message.

Comment: Are you saying that the test is in another class or that the `assertTrue` statement you mentioned in you question is in the `affOrderPageCheck.check` method invocation?  Also, what result are you currently getting?  Is the failed method not executing at all?  Is the test being marked as successful or as a failure?

Comment: The assertTrue is in the affOrderPageCheck.check method, and so marks the test as a failure. It goes to the @Override but the getMessage() method just prints a blank instead of the error message.

Comment: Interesting.  A few more questions: 1) is the `assertTrue` method being invoked by the external class' method JUnit's `Assert.assertTrue` method?  2) does the check method perform any exception handling that could be converting the AssertionError to a different Throwable instance possibly losing the error message? 3) what version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: 1) Yes, it is org.junit.Assert.assertTrue 2) public void check () throws IOException {   3) JUnit4

Comment: If you are receiving an `AssertionError' in the fail method with a blank message, there are only a few causes: a) an assert method was invoked without a message or a null/empty message text b) the original AssertionError was caught and a new error was thrown in its place.  You may want to verify that the check method is not performing other assert logic that is different than the one you mention in your question.